# F# making list of pairs from two lists

Tags: f#

I need to do create a function in F# to pair elements in two lists together(See (ii) in the following picture) :[image]
I'm actually not completely sure what the question is asking: Do I need to create a function that takes two lists and return a list of pairs where ith elements in the resulting list is a pair where first element in the pair is the ith element in the first list and second element in the pair is the ith element in the second list? I don't understand what `*` mean in `val pairlists :'a list * 'b list -> ('a * 'b)list`

If that was what I was suppose to do then here is what i tried:

```
let pairlists (l : 'a list) (m : 'b list) =
    if l.Length <> m.Length then 
        failwith "the two lists does not have the same size"
    else 
        [for i in 1 .. l.Length do
            yield (l.Head,m.Head)

        ]
```

I'm not sure how to do it as I don't know how can i iterate through the lists?
Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate through the lists by pattern matching, which is done using the `match ... with` expression.

For example:

```
f l = 
   match l with
   | head :: tail -> "This list has at least one element!"
   | _ -> "This list is empty"

> f [1]
> "This list has at least one element!"

> f [1; 2]
> "This list has at least one element!"

> f []
> "This list is empty"
```

In your case, there may be several possibilities: both lists are empty, one is empty and the other is not, or both have at least one element:

```
pairlists l m =
    match l, m with
    | (lhead :: ltail), (mhead :: mtail) ->  // both non-empty
    | [], (mhead :: mtail) ->  // first list empty, second is not
    | (lhead :: ltail), [] ->  // second is empty, first is not
    | [], [] ->  // both are empty
```

Now all you need to do is decide what the result of the function should be in each one of these four cases, and then write it down.

I am not going to give you the full answer, since this is obviously homework, but here's another hint: pairing two non-empty lists means pairing their heads (i.e. first elements), then pairing their tails, then attaching the two together.

Answer (score 4):

The `*` in the function signature means that the input is a tuple of two lists and the output is list of tuples.
Simplest way to achieve this is to use List.zip function:

```
let pairlists ((a, b) : 'a list * 'b list) = 
    List.zip a b
```

Here we define the input parameter to be tuple of 'a list and 'b list and pass the lists to `List.zip : 'T1 list -> 'T2 list -> ('T1 * 'T2) list` accordingly

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, although it may be homework, [good questions and answers are good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268190/answers-that-use-a-different-technology-than-what-is-asked/268228#268228). That said, they do specifically state that the lists should be of equal size and since anything else [results in an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.zip%5B't1%2C't2%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) when using `zip`, it's best to provide a more robust suggestion.